# Archiving articles by month on blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, archive

I'm trying to archive the articles on my rails blog by month or what have you. Just some sort of order.

I currently have this in my archives controller

```
     class ArchivesController < ApplicationController


     def index
       @arcticles = Article.all.group_by(:select => "title, id, created_at", :order =                         "created_at DESC")
       @articles_month = @arcticles.group_by { |t| t.due_at.month}
     end
    end
```

And here is my view. I tried going off a railscast episode but feel that maybe its a bit too old and I'm off here. Thoughts anyone? Thanks.

```
   <div class="archives">
    <% @articles_month.each do |month, articles| %>
   <h2><%= month.strftime('%B') %></h2>
     <% for article in articles %>
<strong><%= article.name %></strong> 
    due on <%= article.due_at.to_date.to_s(:long) %> 
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: yeah. no method error for articles_month.

Comment: Please update the question with exact error and full stacktrace.

Comment: I would post the error but I don't have it in front of me anymore. App is functioning at that moment. Thanks for helping though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I figured it out.

Did this in my articles controller

```
   def index
    @article = Article.all
    @articles = Article.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC')
    @articles_by_month = Article.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC').group_by { |article|     article.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
   end
```

view

```
<h2>Archives</h2>

<% @articles_by_month.each do |monthname, articles| %>
<h3="month-archive"><%= monthname %></h3>
  <ul id="archive">
   <% articles.each do |article| %>
  <li class="archive-post"><%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %></li>
<% end %>
<% end %>
  </ul>
```